# Make pagination happen on inner rows, not the group row itself

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination, grouping, ngx-datatable

I'm building a fairly simple solution with ngx-datatables and pagination + grouping.

I can get both things to work independently, but when combining these two, I get the problem that the datatable does the pagination on the "outer" group row.

Lets say I have 200 records with a year field on which I group on and a page "limit" on 10 records/rows. And lets say that there's 40 records with year=2020, then I get 40 rows on the page with the 2020 group row.

You can see an example where it's obvious that the **limit** property is working on group row count and not detail row count here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datatable-expand-row-and-pagination

This is not what I need. I need a table which never shows more than 10 rows per page +/- the group row(s).

I have looked on documentation and search a lot, and I can't find any examples or explanation of how to obtain this behaviour.

Do anyone here know if this is posible and can guide me to how to implement this?

Thanks, Peter from Denmark